# Keychain access and wildcard signing between developer accounts

Tags: ios, wildcard, keychain

I have a bit of an unusual problem. I have a client who is using keychain access to store login credentials for their iOS apps. When I re-sign one of their apps to my provisioning profile (on my own developer account) it, breaks keychain access, which is what I'd expect.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to re-sign their app with my own wildcard provisioning profile and still allow keychain access. I get that it would be easier to just have them add a few of my devices to their portal, so I wouldn't need to re-sign, but they have already used all 100 slots.

I assume that I'll need a custom entitlements file, but I'm not totally sure what changes to make.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

-Jason

Answer (score 0):

Access to keychain element is restricted by the Team ID. This is a 10 character string that can be found on the Member Center here https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#accountSummary. If you look at the provisioning profile in a text editor you will see an element like this

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>XXXXXXXXXX.*</string>
</array>
```

The XXXXXXXXXX corresponds to your Team ID. If the app is trying to store anything into the keychain with a different prefix, it will not work.